# Change the "No such file or directory" message in Bash

Tags: bash

I know it's possible to change the command not found message via .bashrc, but is it possible to use a similar method to change the default "No such file or directory" message? I looked in the bash source code for the solution, and it would seem the best option might be to edit `support/mkclone` and then recompile bash, but for reasons I won't specify, doing that will be a pain in this scenario, so I'm hoping to avoid that if I can and simply go with a solution similar to the command not found solution.

**EDIT:** I'm specifically talking about through the cd command, but I'm hoping to change every possible way that bash can output this message.

Comment: Can you highlight the error condition that will trigger the message you want to replace. This error message can get triggered by many conditions. Sample code will clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Also, our of curiosity, why do you want to change the message. It is a standard message generated from low level system error, and is well understood.

Comment: @dash-o "cd /non_existent_file", and it's because I'm building a custom Linux distribution and want to change the wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete solution, but something worth trying:

Bash is using 'gettext' to translate all messages. Consider setting up a translate file (".po" and ".mo") which will 'translate' into English. For example:

```
msgid "No such file or directory"
msgstr "foo bar"
```

Compile to "mo", and deploy to /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES

I never tried it, but in theory, this should work like translation to any other language.

Possible to make it a global change by apply similar logic to create "libc.mo".